# What would be an effective way to put a marker drawable on the mapview everytime the user clicks the map

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1, android-maps

I am playing around with Android MapView and have come across a requirement, where i have to put a marker at the place where the user clicks.
in my scenario, the user can pan a map , zoom in and out, and click wherever she likes.
in this case, the marker should be put wherever the user is clicking on the map.
If a previous marker was there on map, then at click event it should be cleared and be put at the new place.
This should repeat every time the case repeats.

In future, I'll be having some more drawables like range representative and a pointer to select range which can be dragged.

I am able to put the marker on the first place, but my code doesn't work when the user clicks anywhere else.

Here's the code for the class that I am using: http://pastebin.com/6idn7VwK
The full class extending MapActivity and the one extending the ItemizedOverlay can be found in the link above.

I understand that I might be doing some wrong things, so please correct me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the onTap method for this type of functionality :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView view) {
         // add your marker to the map by creating an overlayItem and calling addOverlay
    }

 public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
     mOverlays.add(overlay);
     populate();
 }
```

Comment: however, i could achieve the same results by using onTouchEvent() and was foolishly using longitude and latitude values, things now work fine, but I am going to give this a try. thanks!

Comment: onTouchEvent is usefull when implementing things like drag & drop. For clicking on a map, onTap is the way to go.

Comment: Perfect. this one solves my purpose more precisely. previously, I was listening for MotionEvent.ACTION_UP that would put a marker everytime the user takes the touch away even after panning too. this one is just perfect. thanks! :-)

Comment: No worries, you'll need action up when dropping your drag :)